# Strsplit split string at every character

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a huge dataset like this:

```
customer_id     customer_math
  15251           10001010
  10101           11111111
  84787           10101010
```

I would like to split the customer_math at every character to receive a df like this:

```
customer_id     2012   2013   2014   2015  2016  2017 2018 2019
  15251           1      0     0       0    1     0     1    0
  10101           1      1     1       1    1     1     1    1   
  84787           1      0     1       0    1     0     1    0
```

I tried but failed.

Can you help me on this?

Many Thanks for your Support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, which does a regex split on the positive lookahead `(?=.)` to generate a split before every character.

```
out <- strsplit(as.character(df$customer_math), "(?=.)", perl=TRUE)
data.frame(df, do.call(rbind, out))

    customer_id customer_math X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   15251       10001010      1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
2   10101       11111111      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3   84787       10101010      1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(customer_id=c(15251, 10101, 84787),
                 customer_math=c(10001010, 11111111, 10101010))
```

**Edit:**

As @Sotos has pointed out, using `strsplit` with `""` empty string as the split character would also work.

Comment: Awesome! You are a star! have a nice day!

Comment: Quick question: Why do have such complicated regex that needs the `perl` argument? Wouldn't the `sep = ''` suffice?

Comment: @GeorgeSoros You are correct, and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution that fixes the column labels could be:

**Code**

```
df %>% 
  mutate(customer_math = str_replace_all(customer_math,
                                         "\\B", " ")) %>% 
  separate(customer_math, 
           into = as.character(2012:2019), 
           sep = " ")
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  customer_id `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019`
        <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1       15251 1      0      0      0      1      0      1      0     
2       10101 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     
3       84787 1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
```

Comment: What's the logic behind that regex? Seems like there are more straight forward ways to split without manipulating the string first. Unless there's some advantage?

Comment: @camille `separate` from `tidyr` wants something to separate upon. My solution was to create a space between each character and then split by space. If you know a better regex to do it I can update my answer :)

Comment: One idea is you can skip the `mutate` step and just use some regex that matches every step between characters, like `"\\B"`

Comment: Thanks @camille, your suggestion improved the solution. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and split every character in different columns.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "customer_math", sep = "", stripWhite = FALSE)

#   customer_id customer_math_1 customer_math_2 customer_math_3 customer_math_4 
#1:       15251               1               0               0               0  
#2:       10101               1               1               1               1  
#3:       84787               1               0               1               0   

#   customer_math_5 customer_math_6 customer_math_7 customer_math_8
#1:               1               0               1               0
#2:               1               1               1               1
#3:               1               0               1               0
```

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like this, I like to keep open the ability to scale to an unknown number of columns. You've got years for columns names starting at 2012, and you might get those years without much hard-coding if you take a couple extra steps to reshape your data.

`tidyr::separate_rows` will split a column and create a row for each item that comes from it. You can use regex such as `"\\B"` to match the non-spaces between each character. Create a year column by counting from 2012 along the number of rows for each ID. Optionally convert those "0"/"1" values to numeric, and reshape back to wide data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate_rows(customer_math, sep = "\\B") %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(year = seq(from = 2012, length.out = n()),
         customer_math = as.numeric(customer_math)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = customer_math)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#> # Groups:   customer_id [3]
#>   customer_id `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019`
#>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1       15251      1      0      0      0      1      0      1      0
#> 2       10101      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
#> 3       84787      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
```